# Speed up disk cloning over USB

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, superduper

My MacBook (13-inch Aluminum Late 2008) lacks a FireWire or Thunderbolt port. So I must attach an external disk ([Voyager](http://www.newertech.com/products/voyagerq.php)) running over USB 2 to do a full backup (cloning disk with [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) app). Not fast, hours and hours.

Any tips or techniques for helping this disk cloning go faster?

Comment: @IconDaemon, While Basil Bourque was really not specific about which '"Late 2008" MacBook' he has, nonetheless since he said "lacks a FireWire or Thunderbolt port" one can therefore assume it's the MacBook 13-inch Aluminum Late 2008, which does not have a FireWire port, it has 2 USB 2.0 ports.  The MacBook 13-inch Late 2008, which has the "White durable polycarbonate" Case, has a single FireWire port and 2 USB ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Disable Spotlight

[Spotlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlight_(software)) is Apple’s technology for indexing all your disk’s contents to facilitate fast searching.

When making a disk clone, you do not want the booted Mac to re-index all that copied content. No need. Worse, Spotlight is fighting for the limited USB to *read* from that external disk while SuperDuper is trying to *write* to that external disk.

Fortunately Apple provides a "Privacy" feature where you can pick a folder, or even an entire disk, telling Spotlight to ignore the nested content. In System Preferences app, in the `Spotlight` option, click the `Privacy` tab. There you can add your external disk to the list of exclusions. Click the plus-icon button and select the external disk.

This sped up my disk-cloning multiple time faster, at least 3-5 times faster. At first, after 10-20 minutes, it looked like 233 gigs would take 24-30 hours to clone. Then I used Spotlight > Privacy. Over 10-20 more minutes, the throughput reported a doubling of speed. Cloning took 4 hours.

[image: screen shot of System Preferences > Spotlight > Privacy]

## Remove Drive

…try at your own risk…

Another option is removing the hard disk from inside the MacBook. Then use Voyager-type or such to attach to another Mac with FireWire/Thunderbolt ports to do the copy.

Removal is easy enough to do if you have a model with a removable battery. The disk is accessible through the battery bay.

The only trick is sometimes the rubber strip that hold the drive in place. If that comes loose while sliding the drive back in, things get tricky.